# Syntax highlighter using the Symfony2 style

Tags: symfony, coding-style, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a website that will hold sample code.  I would like all this sample code to be highlighted so that it looks more stylish.  I was using http://tohtml.com/ to hightlight the code but after seeing the code snippets on the Symfony website (see example below)
[image: Symfony2 syntax highlight]

I decided to try and use their style and after reading [the official Symfony2 page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/format.html) on how to do this, I've come close but still can't seem to get their colours.

Here is what my output currently looks like after I've run my build:
[image]

Does anyone know what I'm missing out on?

**UPDATE**

Sorry forgot to include my code!  This is the contents of my index.txt file as it currently stands:

```
.. code-block:: html+php

    <?php 
        echo $this->foobar(); 
        $i = $i + 1;
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the style loaded in the HTML page?

Comment: I don't think so as my style looks like the default.  However I did add the following code to my source/conf.py file http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/format.html#installing-the-sphinx-extensions I also created a folder called _exts in the source directory and stored the files found here: https://github.com/fabpot/sphinx-php to that new folder (called _exts)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Sphinx? I think you are just looking for a syntax highlighter, that's not the main task of Sphinx... You can just implement the colors in your favourite syntax highlighter. I once implemented them for the Google Code Prettify lib: https://github.com/WouterJ/prettifier/blob/master/prettifier.css

Comment: @WouterJ, I actually just started using Sphinx as that was what the Symfony2 guys were doing.  However seeing as I don't need that all the features it offers, your link is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @n.1, ah.  I see what you meant now.  I thought you were talking about loading the style view the config file.  No the CSS file that is styling the code is currently the "default.css" (which is Sphinx stylesheet -- default theme) I will change that and see what happens.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: @WouterJ, just out of curiosity, what value do you have for html_theme in your conf.py file?  Mine is currently set to "default"